# How to load a YouTube playlist?

Tags: youtube, user-interface, youtube-playlist, youtube-channel

When I search for something on YouTube, and there's a playlist among the search results, I click that list, and it's "loaded" (that is, there's the playlist bar at the bottom of the window, where I can manage the videos; the videos will play one by one automatically; and the rest of the page looks according to the default YouTube theme). **This is exactly what I want.**

Now, if I specifically go to some person's channel, click Playlists, and click the playlist I want, how do I "load" that playlist in the same manner? It just won't load, it will keep me on the person's channel page (looks of which I might hate), and the videos from the playlist will just sit there, in the column to the right, and won't automatically play one by one.

Currently my workaround is:

- Go to the channel.
- Find the playlist I want.
- Copy the name of the playlist into the search box. Search.
- Find the playlist in the search results and click it. Voila, it's "loaded."

I hate doing that every time.
**How do I load** (in the described way) **a playlist I manually selected at someone's channel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method maybe easier than what I am about to tell you but for some reason I can remember this URL.

1. Go to their channel
2. Select "Playlist" on their channel (the tob tabs) you should see the url end (or near the end) with a long list of alphanumeric characters
3. Paste this right before that set of characters `http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL`
4. This will bring you to the playlist page. You can now select play all or play any of the videos

For example on Skillrex channel we have this playlist

More Monsters & Sprites EP

http://www.youtube.com/user/TheOfficialSkrillex#p/c/1B5CF096FA99B653

and switching out for the PL url

http://youtube.com/playlist?list=PL1B5CF096FA99B653

Answer (score -1):

For easy access the playlist, you can copy the playlist and see it under your own playlist.
With YouTube new interface, this save playlist option is gone. there is a blog entry shows you how to copy playlists in YouTube. http://mvcdiary.com/2013/02/14/with-youtube-new-interface-how-to-copy-youtube-playlist-from-another-user/
It uses a third party service http://youtubeplaylist.net, I find it really helps me out of managing playlists.